# Email: is there any header which when present sophisticated email client will not add original email when reply action is hit

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-client

Is there any header which when present sophisticated email client will not add original email when reply action is hit,

For example I get an email: containing text `abc` from `abc@abc.com`, and I reply with `xyz`, I am trying to parse out `xyz` content

There are various ways to do it however

Can I enforce standard client not to include original email's body so parsing of *just* reply can made easier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** The relevant Internet standards do not specify a header to control whether the original text is copied into replies.  Whether to do this or not is left up to the mail client, and a sophisticated one will allow the user to decide whether original text is included or not.